# inconvenience with video call. Agora.io. the best solution?

Tags: agora.io

how should the client be notified that the master is offline. And how to integrate the video call UI similar to Whatsapp. Can anyone suggest the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

that will be a part of your app logic. there are a few ways to implement this but one way to do it is to see if the particular user is running the app on foreground and log that as a flag in your database.

For example here it is using Firebase:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    // user is offline 
    let ref = Database.database().reference.child("isOnline").child(user)
    ref.setValue(false) // NO
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        let ref = Database.database().reference.child("isOnline").child(user)
        ref.setValue(true) // YES
}
```

For the video call UI you can actually easily customize that using one of included UI in the Agora.io [demo apps](https://www.github.com/agoraio)